# rust File::create() sometimes returns os error 32

Tags: windows, file, rust

So i have a function that looks like this:

```
fn write_file(path: &PathBuf, data: Vec<u8>) -> Result<i32,std::io::Error>{
    let mut buffer = File::create(path)?;
    buffer.write_all(&data)?;
    buffer.flush()?;
    Ok(0)
}
```

It gets run in a loop about 10 times per second, taking in a `Vec<u8>` and repeatedly writing it to the same file `tmp.exe`. When I run the program it works perfectly for a few hundred loops but eventually `File::create()` panics with `The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. (os error 32)`.

At first I thought maybe it had something to do with me running the file between writes (even though I wait for an exit code before continuing). So I tried not running it and instead only writing to the file but I still got the same error. Since I'm on windows, I also tried turning off my AV thinking maybe it was doing some kind of check on the newly written file but that didn't fix it either. Any idea what's happening here?

UPDATE: I've managed to isolate the issue into this:

```
use std::path::PathBuf;
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::prelude::*;

fn write_file(path: &PathBuf, data: Vec<u8>) {
    let mut buffer = File::create(path).unwrap(); //error happens here
    buffer.write_all(&data).unwrap();
    buffer.flush().unwrap();
}

fn main() {
    let mut i = 0;
    loop {
        write_file(&PathBuf::from(r"tmp.exe"), vec!(0x90, 0x90, 0x90, 0x90));
        i+=1;
        println!("{}",i);
    }
}
```

which returns

```
2894
2895
2896
2897
2898
2899
thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Os { code: 32, kind: Other, message: "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process." }', src\main.rs:6:22
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
error: process didn't exit successfully: `target\debug\playground.exe` (exit code: 101)
```

Comment: maybe looking at calls relating to `tmp.exe` in Procmon might be interesting.

Comment: I've seen this very same behavior with other languages, in selected windows machines, and the same code works flawlessly in other machines. I still think it has something to do with the antivirus...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright i found a solution, although I'm not sure it's the best one considering it could result in an infinite loop if the file is actually busy. I set it up to simply retry if it encounters Os Error 32

```
fn write_file(path: &PathBuf, data: Vec<u8>) -> Result<i32,std::io::Error>{
    let mut buffer: File = loop {
        match File::create(path) {
            Ok(file) => break file,
            Err(e) => match e.raw_os_error() {
                Some(32) => continue,
                _ => return Err(e)
            } 
        };
    };
    buffer.write_all(&data)?;
    buffer.flush()?;
    Ok(0)
}
```